# Как обновить переменную без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: ajax

Есть кнопка на форме и есть переменная из бд.
 Как сделать, что бы по нажатию на кнопку обновлялась эта переменная?

```
<div class="number">
    <input type="submit" value="Обновить">
</div>

<div id="sum" align="center"> //див с переменной
    {$cart_content[i].cost|replace:'&amp;':'&'}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
$('.number').find('input').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'path/to/handler.php',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){
            $('#sum').find('/*блок, где хранится переменная */').html(response);
        },
        error:function(response){
            alert('error, response - ' + response);
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

Правильнее было бы кнопке добавить отдельный идентификатор, но конкретно в этом случае и так сойдет. 
PHP:

```
<?php 
    $var = //тут производим выборку из БД, если нужна
    echo json_encode($var);
?>
```

Comment: у инпута тип submit - если не предотвратить поведение по умолчанию - перезагрузка все равно пройдет. С Другой стороны, если инпут не внутри тега form, То и так сойдет

Comment: @Grundy, точно, спасибо!)

Comment: @Grundy с третьей стороны, некоторые продукты тайно добавляют скрытую форму на всякий случай :)